# Error with return keyword inside if statement using C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, return-value, break

```
#include<iostream>

int searchAnArray(int *arr, int size, int searchKey);

int main()
{
    const int size = 4;
    int array[] = {345,75896,2,543};
    int searchKey = 2;
    std::cout<<"Found at: "<<searchAnArray(array, size, searchKey);
    return 0;
}

int searchAnArray(int *arr, int size, int searchKey){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" "<<size<<" "<<i<<"\n ";
       if(arr[i] == searchKey){
           return i; break;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
```

I expect that it should return the index value 2 but unfortunately the value returned is -1.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: No point of a break; after the return

Comment: `break;` after `return` is unreachable.

Comment: You return -1 because you have the return -1 in the wrong place. On the first iteration of your for loop if the `if(arr[i] == searchKey){` condition is not true you return -1 and thus your loop ends and you don't iterate

Comment: Look at `if(arr[i] == searchKey){ return i; } else return -1;`. What do you think happens if the first array element is not equal to `searchKey`?

Comment: If the first item in the array is the searchKey, return index 0.  Otherwise if the first item in the array is not the searchKey, then return index -1.

Comment: Even your debug print should show you the mistake.

Comment: Are you under the assumption that `return` somehow "assigns" the return value and that the `break` is needed to avoid overwriting it later in the loop? (This is how assigning to the function's name work in some other languages, so it's not entirely unreasonable.)

Answer (score 2):

you are returning -1 within your for loop, which means that you never search the rest of the array.

Try this instead in searchAnArray():

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
  if(arr[i] == searchKey){
    return i; 
  }
}

return -1;
```

Also, you do not need 'break' when using 'return'.

Comment: This also solves an additional bug. What I mean is if size is 0 it correctly returns -1.

Comment: Or even `auto it = std::find(arr, arr + size, searchkey); return (it == arr + size) ? -1 : std::distance(arr, it);`

Comment: @Jarod42: Care to write that as an answer? C++ standard library techniques are superior in that (i) they are self-documenting, (ii) they might be exploited by compilers in optimisation strategies.

Answer (score 1):

You unconditionally return after first iteration.

Your `return -1;` is misplaced.

it would be:

```
int searchAnArray(const int* arr, int size, int searchKey)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " " << size << " " << i << "\n ";
        if (arr[i] == searchKey) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Your function can be simplified (ignoring debug output) using `std`:

```
int searchAnArray(const int* arr, int size, int searchKey)
{
    const auto it = std::find(arr, arr + size, searchkey);
    return (it == arr + size) ? -1 : std::distance(arr, it);
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the C++ standard library approach in particualar.